# Get minimum per row based on value from another column

Tags: sql, presto

Below is the base table of data..

| date | customer_id | score1 | score2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/22 | a | 1 | 1 |
| 02/01/22 | a | 1 | 1 |
| 01/01/22 | b | 2 | 2 |
| 02/01/22 | b | 4 | 1 |
| 01/01/22 | c | 1 | 1 |
| 02/01/22 | c | 1 | 4 |
| 01/01/22 | d | 5 | 1 |
| 02/01/22 | d | 10 | 1 |

This is the result that I want to achieve, where I only pull through the rows where there has been a change in either score1 or score2 from the previous date. In this case, b has gone from 2 to 4 on score1 and 2 to 1 on score2, c has gone from 1 to 4 on score 2, d has gone from 5 to 10 on score 1.

| date | customer_id | score1 | score2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 02/01/22 | b | 4 | 1 |
| 02/01/22 | c | 1 | 4 |
| 02/01/22 | d | 10 | 1 |

Unsure if there is a function to do this. Altenatively, would it be best to have two separate tables initially and use a join to achieve this. Using SQL presto if that helps.

Many thanks!

Comment: How does the title of this question relate to this problem?  What SQL did you try to solve this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the `LAG()` window function here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t.*, LAG(score, 1, score1) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id
                                            ORDER BY date) AS lag_score_1,
                LAG(score, 1, score2) OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id
                                            ORDER BY date) AS lag_score_2
    FROM yourTable t
)

SELECT date, customer_id, score
FROM cte
WHERE score1 <> lag_score_1 OR score2 <> lag_score_2
ORDER BY date;
```

This answer uses the 3 parameter version of `LAG()`.  The second parameter specifies a step of 1, while the third parameter specifies a default value in case there is no previous value.  In this case, we use `score` as the default such that the earliest record in each customer partition is ignored.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response. I made a slight change to my original question by adding score_2. Is there any chance you could update the answer with that in mind? cheers!